# Deleting item from Dynamic table binding with JSON model

Tags: sapui5

[image]
I'm fetching data from JSON Model and binding it on my table and gave a delete icon to each row and trying to delete that item by clicking that icon so the item deleted from my JSON model but not from my table so how can I delete it from my table.

```
var oModel1 = this.getView().byId("tblOpenAccess").getModel("newModel");
        var oProperty = oModel1.getProperty("/dataProperty");
        var delData = this.getView().byId("tblOpenAccess").getModel("newModel").getProperty("/dataProperty");
        var deleteRecord = oArg.getSource().getBindingContext("newModel").getObject();
        if (length > 1) {
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (delData[i] === deleteRecord) {
                    delData.splice(i,1);
                    oModel1.setProperty("/dataProperty", oProperty);
                    this.getView().byId("tblOpenAccess").getModel("newModel").refresh();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            MessageToast.show("Sorry it can't Delete");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an helper array for such things.

Does your compare step work for you? You are comparing two objects, right? To compare two objects simply use `JSON.stringify(obj)`.

```
var _helpArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < delData.length; i++) {
  if (JSON.stringify(delData[i]) !== JSON.stringify(deleteRecord)) {
    _helpArray.push(delData[i]);
  }
}
oModel1.setProperty("/dataProperty", _helpArray);
```

If your binding right, your table won't show the deleted row anymore.